# Trying to delete row by index value

Tags: mysql

I am using Mysql and C#, trying to delete a row by a column I have called 'index'.  It is an int unique auto increment.

> I want to pass a sql string to executequery (string sql = "DELETE FROM
>   Accounts WHERE index = '123'";)

And have it delete row 1, or what ever row I pass.

> I have also tried it without ' .  "DELETE FROM Accounts WHERE index =
>   123";

When I change the column to something of a string value it works. Like CRN instead of index.  Index is an int and CRN is a string.
But when I try to pass something in C# you can only pass values to the sql connection as string.  So I figure there may be something I have to do to the value I am passing to indicate this part of the string is a number.

Something like

> executequery (string sql = "DELETE FROM Accounts_NWACC WHERE index =
>   '#1'";)

Answer (score 4):

`Index` is a reserved word. Try it like this:

```
DELETE FROM Accounts WHERE `index` = 123
```

It would be a good idea to avoid using reserved words for column names, to avoid these kinds of conflicts. Most people would call it something like `id` instead.

Note that those are backticks (on most keyboards, it's the key above <kbd>TAB</kbd> and left of <kbd>1</kbd>, on the same key as <kbd>~</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

First change executequery to executeUpdate

```
executeUpdate("DELETE FROM Accounts WHERE index ='123'");
```